# Sending activation email for sqlmembership

Tags: c#, authorization

```
private void SendActivationEmail(MembershipUser user)
{
    var message = new MailMessage();
    message.To.Add(user.Email);
    message.Subject = "Attorney Event Notification Activation";

    string urlBase = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath;
    string ActivationUrl = "/ActivateUser.aspx?ID=" + GetUserID(user.Email);
    var fullPath = urlBase + ActivationUrl;            

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "ActivationTemplate.txt"))
    {
        message.Body = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    message.Body = message.Body.Replace("<%UserName%>", user.UserName);
    message.Body = message.Body.Replace("<%ActivationURL%>", fullPath);
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
}
```

How can I clean up this activation email sender?

And is it relatively safe?

Comment: If the user id is a simple integer then the recipient simply try the next number in order to activate another user. One way to prevent this is to generate a GUID to prevent end user from guessing the next number and also have a time window for the GUID to be valid only, say 24 hours from when the email is sent.

Comment: The userID is a GUID. I am using the SQL Membership Provider package in SQL and ASP.NET

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Decoupling**

If we extract the composition of the body to a separate method

```
private String ComposeEmailBody(String userName, String userEmail)
{
    String bodyTemplate = ReadBodyTemplate(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "ActivationTemplate.txt");
    bodyTemplate  = bodyTemplate.Replace("<%UserName%>", userName);

    return bodyTemplate.Replace("<%ActivationURL%>", GetUrlFor(userEmail));
}

private String ReadBodyTemplate(String path, String fileName)
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(path, fileName))
    {
        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

private String GetUrlFor(String userEmail)
{
    return Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) 
         + Request.ApplicationPath  
         + "/ActivateUser.aspx?ID="  
         + GetUserID(userEmail);     
}
```

after introducing an overloaded `SendActivationEmail()` method

```
private void SendActivationEmail(String userName, String userEmail)
{
    var message = new MailMessage();
    message.To.Add(userEmail);
    message.Subject = "Attorney Event Notification Activation";
    message.Body = ComposeEmailBody(userName, userEmail);
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    {
        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
}
```

the former method can be refactored to a call to the overloaded method, which decouples the overloaded one from `MembershipUser`

```
private void SendActivationEmail(MembershipUser user)
{
    SendActivationEmail(user.UserName, user.Email);
}
```

**Nitpicking**

You are mixing the useage of the concrete `type` and `var`

```
string urlBase = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath;
string ActivationUrl = "/ActivateUser.aspx?ID=" + GetUserID(user.Email);
var fullPath = urlBase + ActivationUrl;
```

here it should be either all `var` or all `string`.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a problem with encapsulation and the single responsibility principle here. The method depends on too many external factors, it makes too many external references, and it includes logic of multiple independent responsibilities that would make sense to extract elsewhere.

These are good and belong to this method:

- Creating and filling a `MailMessage` object
- The constant strings for the subject
- The `SmtpClient` object that sends the message

If the method contained only the above,
it would be perfectly reasonable.

But it contains some extra stuff that don't seem to belong:

- The construction logic of `fullPath`. It seems this logic should be somewhere else, for example a centralized router component
- The construction logic of the template file path to read
- The replacement of the template parameters `UserName` and `ActivationURL` would also be good to extract to a component. There should be a component in charge of user templates and the template parameters, which naturally takes a user template and returns properly formatted text. That way, if the template changes, the logic of the template parameters will be closer to the logic that fills those parameters, making the code more cohesive.

Lastly, as a minor remark, the variable naming is not consistent.
Most of the local variables are `camelCase`, except `ActivationUrl`:

> ```
> string urlBase = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath;
> string ActivationUrl = "/ActivateUser.aspx?ID=" + GetUserID(user.Email);
> ```

It would be better to use `camelCase` consistently.

Comment: I don't know how that variable name slipped through, I was trying my best to be consistent on the naming too.  thanks for the review.